# Django and React getting 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, create-react-app

I've used create-react-app combined with Django Rest Framework to make a small site. Everything works perfectly when I use `npm start` and hit the Django API from one port to another. When I `npm build` the static react files and serve them from within the Django app, however, I get `403 forbidden` when hitting a number of endpoints. I think it has something to do with CSRF, but I can't figure out what.

I serve the static files from `views.py`:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def serve_html(request):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(REACT_APP_DIR, 'build', 'index.html')) as f:
            return HttpResponse(f.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return HttpResponse(
            """
            This URL is only used when you have built the production
            version of the app. Visit http://localhost:3000/ instead, or
            run `yarn run build` to test the production version.
            """,
            status=501,
        )
```

My `urls.py` contains the catchall for the static files at the bottom:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ..all api paths
    url(r'^', serve_html, name='serve_html'),
]
```

I use `TokenAuthentication` and `SessionAuthentication`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

And the api requests that require users to be logged in have the following decorators:

```
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
```

**Addendum:** I notice that when running it cross-origin, there is no `sessionid` cookie (and things work), but when I try to host react files on same-origin, there is a `sessionid` cookie (and `403 Forbidden` is returned).

Sorry for the open-endedquestion, but I'm at my wit's end here; I really don't know why it's not working.

Comment: for endpoints with `IsAuthenticated` you need to pass token.

Comment: what is the result in terminal when run `curl -X GET http://xxx/yoururl/ -H 'Authorization: Token 69b...07'`

Comment: I pass the token for all endpoints requiring it like so: `await fetch(`${API_HOST}/logout`,{ method: 'POST', headers: {'Authorization': `Token ${Cookies.get('auth_token')}`}});`

Answer (score 6):

You do not require the `SessionAuthentication` class since you are using a token-based HTTP Authentication scheme. This should do the trick:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Hope this helps.